# Embedding Rails DB as_json.to_json into Javascript not working. (turns into &quot stuff)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have looked up almost every SO past question to no avail.

I have `main.html.erb file` and I'm mixing html/erb/javascript in it. (I know it's not a good thing but I'm still confused with asset pipelines and it's fairly a small project.)

Here, I want to put some DBs called from the controller into javascript code, so that I can put my Rails DB into Javascript variable, in JSON form.

Here's what my .erb code looks like:

```
//I want to put my Rails data into JS variable, in JSON form.

var OUR_SELLER_DB = new Object(); 

<% @db_json.each do |p|%>
    OUR_SELLER_DB.push(<%=p.to_json %>);
<% end %>
```

and my Controller:

```
@db = Post.all  
@db_json = @db.as_json
```

I tried to debug and checked my browser's console. It seems `p` iterator which is supposed to be each elements in `@db_json` comes out in some weird shape.

```
OUR_SELLER_DB.push('{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;user_id&quot;:1,&quot;category_id&quot;:1,&quot;type_id&quot;:1,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;test ...blablabla...&quot;:&quot;2017-08-17T17:39:15.278Z&quot;}');
```

(I found a funny thing. The above comes out just fine in good-old JSON form if I just paste it here without a code block. What is it??)

> Uncaught TypeError: OUR_SELLER_DB.push is not a function
>       at main:95

So why is it changing itself into some crazy form?
Most important of all, how do I fix this and get my desired JS variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OUR_SELLER_DB is an object. Objects do not indeed have method `push`. Did you mean it to be an array?

> So why is it changing itself into some crazy form?

That "crazy form" is called "html escaping". And if you don't do that by default, bad things will happen. Try this to bypass escaping:

```
<%= raw p.to_json %>
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer but I was editing my whole question cause I felt like it didn't have any valid point. I found out <%= %> part midway but still don't know how I can 'push' each hash into JS variable. 
I'll try to change OUR_SELLER_DB to Array and come back.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are intending to do is output an array you can just call:

```
var OUR_SELLER_DB = <%= raw( @db_json ) %>
```

Using `raw` will avoid the quotes being escaped as rails uses a secure by default scheme where strings are untrusted and are html escaped by default.

Comment: Provided that `@db_json` is a collection of objects or something array like.

Comment: Judging from sample code, it is derived from `Post.all`, so yeah, a collection.

Comment: Missed that part. Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: "calling to_json twice" - nope. The first one is `.as_json`